# Why doesn't batch normalization 'zero out' a batch of size one?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I'm using Tensorflow. Consider the example below:

```
>>> x
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.22630838], dtype=float32)>
>>> tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.22619529], dtype=float32)>
```

There doesn't seem to be any change at all, besides maybe some perturbation due to epsilon.
Shouldn't a normalized sample of size one just be the zero tensor?

I figured maybe there was some problem with the fact that the batch size = 1 (variance is zero in this case, so how do you make the variance =1)
But I've tried other simple examples with different shapes and setting the

```
axis=0,1,etc
```

parameter to different values. None of them make any change at all, really.

Am I simply using the API incorrectly?

Comment: You need to run the layer in training mode: ```
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x, training=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running the batch norm with a running mean and it joins the mean and std of the single sample with the initial values of the mean and var. Try setting momentum to 0 (I think, also try 1, the point is to turn off the running calculation), and then, I guess it might solve the problem.